# Read table from Cygwin MySQL into Matlab, with sporadic administrator rights

Tags: mysql, matlab, odbc

In the past, I've programmatically imported tables from Excel and Access files into Matlab.  Now I have to import data that is in the form of an MySQL dump, consisting of machine generated SQL code, with a large volume literal data insertion statements.  Not having any experience with SQL daemon/client models, [this experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941092/how-to-safely-terminate-mysqld) served as the initial step of getting MySQL running in Cygwin without administrator rights.

To ingest the data from MySQL, I looked at what came up with a Matlab documentation search for [MySQL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=mysql).  Matlab documentation says that JDBC connections are best reserved for Java environments, so I am following [this ODBC guidance for Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-odbc-windows.html?searchHighlight=mysql&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) (there is no page specifically for Cygwin).  Due to many restrictions, I have not updated the Cygwin packages; the ODBC drivers are version 5.2.5-1.

In following the above Matlab guidance for ODBC, the first thing that happens when I try to configure an ODBC data source using the Database Explorer is that I am prompted for administrator rights to run `ODBC Administrator`.  I will have to request this, but I was wondering what other steps require administrator rights will be needed?  I don't want to return to the well for a request each and every step of the way.

As well, will the ODBC Administrator somehow know how to use the Cygwin ODBC driver for MySQL, or does the MySQL daemon automatically know how to use this because the package is installed?  Not having dealt with the Database Explorer in my past programmatic ingestion of Excel/Access data, I'm not sure how the driver is used, what process invokes it, and whether the user has to do anything to trigger this.  I'm not even sure if the daemon is involved in the connection.  Alternatively, is there a way directly read the MySQL `*.frm` file for each table (or is that what is actually done via the connection)?

Note that my installation of Cygwin was done with the `--no-admin` option to the `setup` program.  That is, all Cygwin processes are owned by my non-administrator account.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running MATLAB in Cygwin?

Comment: No.  It is a commercial product and doesn't come as a cygwin package.  I just have our installer person install it on Windows 7, then double-click the icon.